# where conditions for same specials IDs cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

how to use where conditions in posts model for same specials IDs
and how to receive title of special IDs in view

```
$items = $this->Posts->find()->where(['AND'=>[['id'=>3],['id'=>4],['id'=>5]]]);  
$this->set(compact('items'));
```

view:

```
$items->id[0]->title
```

Comment: You want to find posts where the id is simultaneously 3, 4 and 5? That's not ever going to be the case. I expect you want to find posts where the id id 3, 4 *or* 5? `->where(['id IN' => [3,4,5]])`. And in your view, `id` won't be an array, `items` will.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your query in controller

```
// in controller
$items = $this->Posts->find()->where(['id IN'=>[3,4,5]]);  
$this->set(compact('items'));
```

... and then you can access the titles in template by iterating over generated result

```
// in template
<?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
    <div><?= h($item->title) ?></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Code only answers are rarely helpful. Please comment your code or expound on why this is the solution to the question.